# Procedure that checks if values exist

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm still new to PL/SQL and what I'm trying to do is to create a procedure that will display an output activity along with a count of clubs. If the input activity is not on record, then display a message like "activity not in database" or whatever. I have created a function already, I now need to call this function to perform what I have described.

My function is:

```
     create or replace function ex3b_activity_check (club_id_in in number) 
       return boolean is
       act integer;
       begin
        select activity into act 
        from club_activity
        where club_id = club_id_in;

       if act is not null then
        return true;
       else
        return false;
       end if;
      end;
```

My procedure is not giving me the desired results. The tables are like this

```
SPORTING_CLUBS TABLE

CLUB_ID - NAME - STREET - CITY - STATE - ZIP - PHONE - FEE
-------   -----  ------   -----  -----   ----  ----- -----


CLUB_ACTIVITY TABLE

CLUB_ID - ACTIVITY
-------   --------
```

I have spent more time trying to troubleshoot it than anything else. Any help is much appreciated thank you.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data within the two tables? What is the problem you are facing - no rows being returned, incorrect rows being returned etc.

Comment: My procedure is not really compiling correctly. thus I have no return of data

Comment: @user3311980 It would be helpful to paste the error that you are actual getting. It is hard to deduce the error from a huge set of error messages by just looking at the source code

Comment: How are you calling your function? If you are calling it in SQL context, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260238/function-returning-boolean-fails-on-expression-is-of-wrong-type should help you.

Comment: At first glance I can't see any obvious reason that your function wouldn't compile. Please edit your question and include the error you're getting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommand to use boolean since it is not recogize with the pure sql, anyway You can use your function like the following:

```
declare MyValue boolean;
begin
   MyValue := ex3b_activity_check(1);
end;
```

What I reccomand to use varchar2, which will return a single charachter of Y or N, like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EX3B_ACTIVITY_CHECK (CLUB_ID_IN IN NUMBER)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   COUNT_IT   NUMBER;

BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(ACTIVITY)
     INTO COUNT_IT
     FROM CLUB_ACTIVITY
    WHERE CLUB_ID = CLUB_ID_IN;

   IF COUNT_IT = 0 
   THEN
      RETURN 'N';
   ELSE
      RETURN 'Y';
   END IF;
END;
```

Then you can easly use it like

```
Select EX3B_ACTIVITY_CHECK(1) from dual;
```